# mysql_affected_rows returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with `mysql_affected_rows()` function in PHP. I use MySQL update, in phpMyAdmin I can see, that 'confirmed' changes from 0 to 1, but `mysql_affected_rows` still returns 0! I cannot find a solution. My code is:

```
$query = "UPDATE visits                 
SET confirmed = 1
WHERE id = ? AND confirmed = 0 AND expire >  now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;";


$stmt = $this->conn->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id); //$id is a function parameter
$res = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

echo mysql_affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: [`$stmt->affectedRows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everyone seems to think you using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), whereas it looks more like [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to me, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) is the MySQLi way:

```
$query = "
  UPDATE visits                 
  SET confirmed = 1
  WHERE id = ?
    AND confirmed = 0
    AND expire > now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
";

$stmt = $this->conn->stmt_init();

if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id); //$id is a function parameter
  $res = $stmt->execute();
  echo $stmt->affected_rows; // Here's the good stuff
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're using PDO, not the mysql_* functions.
Therefore, you should uso PDOs rowCount function:

```
$query = "UPDATE visits                 
    SET confirmed = 1
    WHERE id = ? AND confirmed = 0 AND expire >  now() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;";

$stmt = $this->conn->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id); //$id is a function parameter
    $res = $stmt->execute();

    echo $stmt->rowCount();

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: @Bono, not true. For PDO the rowCount function does return rows affected.

Comment: Unfortunately when I use this, I get Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::rowCount()

Comment: Thats because you forgot to mention you were using mysqli, so from your code, I assumed it was PDO, but this assumption proved wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to get the number of affected rows when using an `UPDATE` statement :

```
$stmt = $this->conn->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id); //$id is a function parameter
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

It also needs to be before the `close()` statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

The PDOStatement::rowCount return the number of rows affected by the query

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the connection as a parameter to the function.

```
echo mysql_affected_rows($this->conn);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php